# Prestashop product in a specific category

Tags: prestashop, categories, product, prestashop-1.7

I am using Prestashop 1.7 and I want to check if a product is in a specific category and change the image on the product.tpl

```
{if $product->id_category_default == 10}
```

is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the field `$product->id_category_default` stored a value only main (~first) category id. If your product is in a few categories, relations stored in table `category_product`. You can access to array of all categories of a product by using `$product->getWsCategories()`. You can see it like this:

```
{$product->getWsCategories()|var_dump}
```

As you want to check if product is in a special category, you should do like this:

```
        {foreach from=$product->getWsCategories() key='k' item='category'}
            {if $category.id == 7760}
                here you insert something
            {/if}
        {/foreach}
```

**Edited:**

Previous method works well in Prestashop 1.4, but developers modified $product object to array, so you cannot run object functions anymore.

I found a solution for 1.7 version. See:

```
{foreach from=Product::getProductCategoriesFull(Tools::getValue('id_product')) item=category}
    {$category|var_dump}
        {if $category.id_category== '1041'}
            // here you can insert img
        {/if}
{/foreach}
```

It works by similar way.

Comment: thanks for your answer. If i using {$ product-> getWsCategories () | var_dump} in product.tpl i see nothing. The whole website is down and nothing will be loading.

Comment: @Sebastian try to enable debug mode.

Comment: @Sebastian, I'm not sure, but your version of Prestashop may not have var_dump plugin. But foreach code should work well

Comment: FatalThrowableError in smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157) : eval()'d code line 42: Call to a member function getWsCategories() on array

Comment: thanks for your help. Really good. But i needed to change this part. {foreach from=Product::getProductCategoriesFull($product.id) item=category} Tools::getValue('id_product') with $product.id

Comment: @Sebastian, OK, but it isn't necessary - `Tools::getValue('id_product')` contain the product ID as well :)